# Fetch post data from dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm using javascript to generate `input` fields in a form. The form looks as follows:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="team_name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="main_member" value="" />
    // every time a div is clicked, javascripts appends a new text input to the
    // form with name="members[]"
</form>
```

I am unable to fetch the posted data for the dynamically created `input` fields in php.

Here's the php:

```
$team_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['team_name']);
$main_member = htmlspecialchars($_POST['main_member']);

$members = $main_member . join(',', $_POST['members[]']);

$STH = $DBH->prepare( "
        INSERT INTO teams (id, team_name, members)
        VALUES (NULL, '" .$team_name. "', '" .$members. "')
    " );
$STH->execute();
```

The database shows only the `$main_member` having been inserted. The php is not picking up the dynamically generated `input` fields.

What am I missing?

Comment: try $members = $main_member . join(',', $_POST['members']);

Comment: @DavidEricsson, thanks it works fine now! Please post as an answer so I can accept and vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$members = $main_member . join(',', $_POST['members[]']);
```

will not work. `$_POST['members']` is the array generated by the form, which you can join on.

So it should be :

```
$members = $main_member . join(',', $_POST['members']);
```